# How do I make an optional parameter in a slash command (Pycord)

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I have a slash command in my Pycord bot.
Here is the code:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='greet', description='Greet someone!')
async def greet(ctx, name):
    await ctx.send('Hello ' + name + '!')
```

How would I make "name" an optional parameter? I tried setting name=None, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You could simply set the default value of name to an empty string `async def greet(ctx, name=''):`

Comment: Wow, this works, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The first way is the easiest and laziest way which is just setting the parameter to a default value as such:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='greet', description='Greet someone!')
async def greet(ctx, name=''):
    await ctx.respond(f'Hello {name}!')
```

The second way that I know of is from the example code in the [Pycord repository](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord):

```
from discord.commands import Option

@bot.slash_command(name='greet', description='Greet someone!')
async def greet(ctx, name: Option(str, "Enter your friend's name", required = False, default = '')):
    await ctx.respond(f'Hello {name}!')
```

EDIT:

`await ctx.send(f'Hello {name}!')` was changed to `await ctx.respond(f'Hello {name}!')` because discord requires a response from a slash command otherwise discord will show an ugly error message saying that there was no response.

UPDATE:

As of June 2022, you can write your slash commands with the default parameter value expressed in the decorator:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='greet', description='Greet someone!')
@option(
    "name", 
    description="Enter your friend's name",
    required=False,
    default=''
)
async def greet(
    ctx: discord.ApplicationContext,
    name: str
):
    await ctx.respond(f"Hello {name}!")
```

Answer (score 1):

you could find examples from pycord repo [examples/app_commands](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/tree/master/examples/app_commands)

```py
# example.py

import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.commands.context import ApplicationContext
from discord.commands import Option
from discord.file import File
import os

# example for getting image
def get_image_paths():
    file_paths = []

    for fn in os.listdir('./img'):
        file_paths.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'img', fn))

    return file_paths

async def images(ctx : ApplicationContext):
    imgs = get_image_paths()

    files = [File(path) for path in imgs]

    await ctx.respond(files=files)

async def say_hello(ctx  : ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.respond(f"hello")

# guild_ids are optional, but for fast registration I recommand it
# name (optional) : if not provided, your command name will shown as function name; this case "my_command"
@commands.slash_command(
    name = "my_command",
    description= "This is sample command",
    guild_ids = [ <your guild(server) id> ],
)
async def sample_command(
    ctx : ApplicationContext,
    opt: Option(str,
                    "reaction you want", 
                    choices=["Hi", "image"], 
                    required=True)
):

    if opt == "Hi":
        await say_hello(ctx)

    if opt == "image":
        await images(ctx)
```

it will look like :

[image]

[image]

[image]

import this script as `from example import library_command`

and don't forget to add commands

```py
# at main.py
...

bot.add_application_command(library_command)
...

bot.run(<your token>)
```

you must send as 'respond' not 'send' or discord will count as "failed to reply"